# Refresh WMS and WMSC with openscales 1.1.8

Tags: apache-flex, maps, openstreetmap, wms

well, I'm developing with [openscales](http://openscales.org/documentation/index.html) API for flex and I wanna know how can I refresh a WMSC or even a WMS without having to extend this classes.
att,
Andre Mariano